# Unity and Apple/Google ID access?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

After extensive internet research, I have not come up with a way to access Apple ID's or Google ID's from Unity running on respective devices... either ID's or something else unique to the accounts logged in.

I don't know if this is possible with Unity or maybe a plugin exists. If not, how would you go about getting this?

Comment: Not sure why you didn't find this: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Comment: Yes I found this thanks. Problem is this does not give me the currently logged in account ID.

Comment: If you need this id for uniqueness and not for an email address, there is always `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`.

Comment: On android the user doesn't have to be logged in to an google account or can have many. You can retrieve this account data from an native plug in if you have the required permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Ahh understood thanks!